# How do I create a 50x3 cell array from a 50x3 matrix. Keep just getting a 1x1 cell array with a 50x3 submatrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell-array

Using this code but it keeps just giving me a 1x1 cell array

```
mynewcellarray = mat2cell(oldmatrix, 50, 3)
```

Comment: Do you want a 50x3 cell array where each cell contains only one number?

Comment: My bad, this was not the duplicate, [this one was](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336152/how-do-you-convert-a-matrix-to-a-cell-array-of-equivalent-size)!

Comment: if you want to use `mat2cell` in the future though, you should have done this: `mat2cell(oldmatrix, ones(50,1), ones(1,3))`

Answer (score 4):

You should use [`num2cell`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html):

```
mynewcellarray=num2cell(oldmatrix)
```