# How do you convert a matrix to a cell array of equivalent size?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm trying to convert a 50 x 3 matrix into a 50 x 3 cell array, and I seem to be doing something wrong. Every time I try I'm left with a 1 x 1 cell array with the entire matrix in one cell.

Answer (score 2):

You want [NUM2CELL](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html)

```
num2cell(rand(50,3)); % gives 50x3 cell.
```